# Spring TestCode error : Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

#### I write test code but its code calls many error messages.

I think the main error message is

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource' defined in class path resource [com/server/Dotori/config/exception/MessageConfiguration.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.messages.basename' in value "${spring.messages.basename}"

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.messages.basename' in value "${spring.messages.basename}"
```

this.

how I do .. give me answer

Even the codes that were passed in the past have failed.

I don't see what the problem is.

##### I Did ~

- restart docker
- restart h2 database

Comment: Hi, could you post your `.properties` files and/or `.xml` files like `applicationContext.xml` of your application if you have any.

Comment: This question is rather short and lacking a lot of information. Most importantly the Code of your test file and your application.properties but I'll still give it a shot and try and answer it. Are you loading your application properties using "@TestPropertySource" or "@PropertySource"?